# jQuery Text Opacity with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, fade, horizontal-scrolling

I can't quite figure out why this isn't working. I have some text introducing images to the right of it. As the user scrolls to view the images I want the text to gradually fade away. I've seen plenty of examples of vertical text fading with the same code but for some reason this isn't working for me. Anybody see anything I'm doing wrong? I have the following javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind("projectLoadComplete", function(){
        if ($(".project_intro")[0]){
            var divs = $('.project_intro');
            $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
                var st = $(this).scrollLeft();
                divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/250) });
                if (divs.css('opacity') < 0) {
                    divs.css('opacity', 0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And the following HTML code:

```
<div class="project_intro">This is some intro text that I want to fade when the user scrolls left.</div>
<table height="100%" style="height: 100%; margin-left: 300px;" valign="middle">
    <tr>
        <td>{image 1}</td>
        <td>{image 2}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like your code is alright minus some subjective changes. I would take a look at [this link](http://support.cargocollective.com/customer/portal/questions/1282858-projectloadcomplete-not-triggering-) in regards to your `bind`. Also if you could give a bit more information like any errors in your console or if you can trigger it manually it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle for you at http://jsfiddle.net/5xQb3/6/

it works for me after i replaced the `bind('projectLoadComplete ')` to `document.ready()` are you sure your projectLoadComplete event is firing?

Answer (score 0):

```
Don't go for the hardest thing dude.
Use fadeOut jquery method...
fadeOut('Ur time in milliseconds without quotes')

$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(".project_intro")[0]){
        var divs = $('.project_intro');
        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            var st = $(this).scrollLeft();
           $('.project_intro').fadeOut(5000);
        });
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5xQb3/16/)